# Why looping through hdus at pos=2 in fits files is much slower than looping through hdus at pos=1?

Tags: performance, astropy, fits

I am looping through a number of fits-files. All my fits-files have the same structure and contain within them 3 tables (hdus). I can loop through the tables at position 1 within each file the following way:

```
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.table import Table

for file_name in fits_files_list[:100]:
    table1 = Table.read(file_name, hdu=1)
```

This happens very quickly and takes only 1.75 sec for the first 100 files or ~20 ms for 1 file. I can also loop through the tables at position 2 of the files by just changing `hdu=1` to `hdu=2` but this increases the loop time by a 10 fold! This matters to me, because I frequently have to loop through tens of thousands of fits files, so the total time could be hours. Strangely enough, the tables at position 2 are smaller (~27 KB) than the tables at position 1 (~130 kB). Further, tables at position 1 have shape 2833 rows * 8 columns and tables at position 2 have shape 1 row * 126 columns. You can download an example of such a file from here (from a research archive containing astronomical data)

`https://data.sdss.org/sas/dr16/eboss/spectro/redux/v5_13_0/spectra/lite/3699/spec-3699-55517-0420.fits`

Why is looping through the tables at position 2 so much slower? Can I increase the speed somehow? Are there any workarounds to decrease the time for looping? Tnx

Comment: are you closing each file after opening them?

Comment: @MitchWheat Hm, I thought this is required when using `astropy.fits.open`, but not required (or even possible) when using `astropy.table.read`. At least here they say nothing about it: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/io.html Do you know how I can close the files in the minimal code I present above?

Comment: you're no doubt correct; I'm not really familiar with  astropy.fits

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/12491 the reason in this very specific case has little to do with the order of the HDUs, and more to do that in these files the second table HDU has a great deal more columns than the first one, and the time is dominated by constructing all those columns.

FITS also has an unfortunate, unavoidable overhead associated with reading later HDUs in a file, because there is no easily found index in a FITS file telling you were each HDU lives.  The only way is to parse the header for each HDU in order to find where the next one is.  `astropy.io.fits` already goes through a fair bit of effort to make that as efficient as possible.

Here's a brief experiment I did to demonstrate this:

```
# issue12491.py
from astropy.io import fits                                                     
                                                                                
filename = 'spec-3699-55517-0420.fits'                                          
                                                                                
def warmup():                                                                   
    hdul = fits.open(filename)                                                  
    tbhdu = hdul[1]                                                             
    tbhdu.data                                                                  
    tbhdu = hdul[2]                                                             
    tbhdu.data                                                                  
                                                                                
@profile                                                                        
def main():                                                                     
    hdul = fits.open(filename)                                                  
    tbhdu = hdul[1]                                                                
    tbhdu.data                                                                     
    tbhdu = hdul[2]                                                                
    tbhdu.data                                                                     
                                                                                   
warmup()                                                                           
main()
```

```
$ kernprof -l -v issue12491.py 
Wrote profile results to issue12491.py.lprof
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0.221764 s
File: issue12491.py
Function: main at line 14

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    14                                           @profile
    15                                           def main():
    16         1       3227.0   3227.0      1.5      hdul = fits.open(filename)
    17         1        956.0    956.0      0.4      tbhdu = hdul[1]
    18         1       7905.0   7905.0      3.6      tbhdu.data
    19         1       1119.0   1119.0      0.5      tbhdu = hdul[2]
    20         1     208557.0 208557.0     94.0      tbhdu.data
```

You can see the time is entirely dominated by reading the data in the second HDU, and further exploration I discussed in the issue demonstrates that most of that overhead has to do simply with the large number of columns.  But test cases like this are good for finding opportunities for small optimizations.

Comment: Thank you for the invested effort! Do you know of any workaround that would speed up my task of looping through fits files and extracting data from multiple hdus?